# Laravel default param on route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to structure my web like this:

```
myapp.com/{myworkspace}/*
```

Where `{myworkspace}` is a dynamic param, and `*` is all the ulrs of the web.

I only got the myworkspace param once the user is logged in, due to it's a field of my users table. I don't want to pass it every time I call the route helper, also is unnecesary for the controllers actions.

So, I have a problem setting this parameter and I tried so many ways like middelwares, sessions, service providers and `URL::defaults` method too. I think I am missing something important, and I cant achieve it in any other ways.

Could anybody help me, please?

**UPDATE**

I'm trying routes like this:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
    ...
    Route::prefix('{workspace}')->group(function () {
        ...
        Route::get('/example', 'SomeController@show')->name('example.show')
    });
});
```

When I try to use `{{route(example.show)}}`, throws the exception `Missing required parameters for [Route: example.show]`.

Comment: Please clarify more with code example, and what you are trying to achieve,

Comment: `unnecesary for the controllers actions`  so where do you use the param?

Comment: It is only for user information, to provide a logical structure for them.

Answer (score 0):

In your setup, `example.show` is a route that is prefixed with `{workspace}`.

`{workspace}` is a dynamically defined route parameter, so Laravel can't work out what that is - you'll need to define it when you try and generate the route.

So, for example, if my workspace is "rich", `{{route(example.show)}}` would become:

```
{{ route(example.show, ['workspace' => 'rich']) }}
```

Laravel's documentation on [named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#named-routes) has a brief example.

### **Edit**

If you've chosen to use the `route()' function to generate your urls inside your blade files, and you have a common route parameter that needs to be defined on a regular basis, I'd consider writing a helper function to make this easier. So instead of:

```
{{ route(example.show, ['workspace' => 'rich']) }}
```

This could become:

```
{{ MyHelperClass::generateWorkspaceRoute('example.show') }}
```

And then in your helper class file:

```
public function generateWorkspaceRoute($routeName) 
{
    $workspace = $this->getWorkspace();

    return route($routeName, ['workspace' => $workspace]);
}

private function getWorkspace() 
{
    // Your logic to determine workspace here.
    // If it is possible that we are generating this without an
    // authenticated user, then provide a fallback...
    return \Auth::check() ? \Auth::user()->workspace : 'workspace';
}
```

You can then look out for your fallback in your controller, and redirect
the authenticated user to their correct workspace:

```
// in SomeController
public function show($workspace)
{
    if($workspace === 'workspace') {
        // Because our controller is behind the 'auth' middleware, 
        // we should now be able to generate a correct workspace route
        return redirect(MyHelperClass::generateWorkspaceRoute('example.show'));
    }

    // Normal controller logic continues from here...
}
```

**Note:** this requires knowledge of what your "fallback" workspace will be at the time of generating this for each user - if you are allowing your users to define this then you will need to prevent them from choosing your fallback as an option.

Comment: You're rigth, but I already know how route params works. What I need to archive, is to load `{workspace} ` param without the needed to pass it in every route since it is a prefix to all web's routes

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a route prefix? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-prefixes

Comment: I've edited my answer to include some thoughts on making it easier for providing the workspace parameter

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help, but I've already tried that. In that case, my problem is that I'm not be able to use `/Auth::user()` in the helper class, if I could, I would use route prefix like: `Route::prefix( MyHelperClass::generateWorkspace() ) `

Comment: Hmm ok so it sounds like you’re looking for some help in automating the retrieval of the workspace parameter? For that I think we’d need to know more about where it is coming from?

Comment: Re-reading your question, it sounds like your workspace parameter is a field in the User model, and I can see that you have the routes wrapped in the ‘auth’ middleware (which requires users to be logged-in) - so why can’t you use \Auth::user() ?

Comment: Cause `\Auth::user()`always return `null` in that Helper class.

Comment: Ok, in the case where your blade views are being displayed to non-authenticated users (in which case you won't have access to `Auth::user()`), I've edited my answer to provide some thoughts on how that could be handled in the route generator.